# Why LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue() fails on machines in domain

Tags: .net, printing

I have simple windows service(Log on: Local System) with start/stop as given below:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    EventLog.WriteEntry(SOURCE, "Start");
    var queue = LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue();
}
protected override void OnStop()
{
    EventLog.WriteEntry(SOURCE, "Stop");
}
```

It works on my local Win 7(x64), but fails to start on Win 7(x64) in domain.
I see exception:

> Service cannot be started. System.Printing.PrintServerException: An
>   exception occurred while getting the default printer. Win32 error: The
>   system cannot find the file specified.
>        at System.Printing.LocalPrintServer.GetDataFromServer(String property, Boolean forceRefresh) at
>   System.Printing.LocalPrintServer.GetUnInitializedData(String[]
>   properties) at
>   System.Printing.LocalPrintServer.get_DefaultPrintQueue() at
>   System.Printing.LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue() at
>   blablabla.Service1.OnStart(String[] args) at
>   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object
>   state)

Can anybody help with that? 
Thank you.

p.s. I guess that LocalSystem should have profile. And I know that my default printer is not default printer for LocalSystem...

Comment: Hmm when I try `new PrinterSettings().PrinterName` it tells me: "Default printer is not set"

Answer (score 0):

Local system does not have a profile...

I think you should handle the lack of default printer... And so of default print queue.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.printing.localprintserver(v=vs.110).aspx

methods such getprintqueues looks like interesting for your purpose..